# call python function on a html button click in flask

Tags: python, html, jquery, flask

I have written a sample code where I want to call a python function defined in a python file (not the page, just the function) through a html button click in flask. please help me to find the proper way to do this.

Below is the jquery script to trigger action on button click I have written in base.html. button_click() is the function defined in routes.py which i want to call on button click.

```js
    <script>
        $('#btn-click').on('click', function(e) {
            {{button_click()}}
        });       
    </script>
```

Below is the entire code sample

**main.py**

```
from Website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

****init**.py**(underscore not visible)

```
from flask import Flask
from .routes import routes

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)    
        #..........................Register blueprint.......................#
    app.register_blueprint(routes, url_prefix='/')
    
    return app
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="english">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href={{url_for('static', filename='images/logo1.png')}}>

    <title>{% block title%}{% endblock %}</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->    
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Bootstrap icons css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={{url_for('static', filename='bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css')}}>

    <!-- Font Awesome JS (icons) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={{url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/style.css')}}>

</head>

<body>

    <!--............................Home page navbar................................-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top bg-light py-lg-0 " id="customNavbar">  
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                <!-- Add logo -->
                <img src={{url_for('static', filename='images/logo1')}} alt="logo">
            </a>
            
            <button class="navbar-toggle-collapsed d-block d-sm-block d-md-none" type="button"
                    data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-target="#navbarResponsive"
                    aria-controls="navbarResponsive" 
                    aria-expanded="true" 
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                    id="togglerButton">
                    
                    <span class="line"></span> 
                    <span class="line"></span> 
                    <span class="line" style="margin-bottom: 0;"></span>
            </button>
    
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">                        
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div> 

            <form class="lg-flex">  

            <!-- Button to call function -->
                <button type="button" name='signin-btn' class="btn buttonCustom" id='btn-click'>Click Me</button>
            </form>
        </nav>    
    </div>

    <!--...............Home content.......................--> 
    {% block navPages%}{% endblock%}

    <!-- javascript to enable bootstrap usage -->    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $('#btn-click').on('click', function(e) {
            {{button_click()}}
        });       
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block navPages%}
    <h1> Home Page! </h1>
{% endblock%}
```

Comment: you can define path for function like `api-func`  you want to call, then use fetch from js or you can use `xhr` in jquery to call the `api-func` url path

Comment: Could you please show show me a code snippet how I can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Python is executed on the server side. JS is for the client-side. You cannot call Python code from JS.
You need to make an (asynchronous ?) HTTP call to a route defined in Flask.
You can see my response to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68785360/show-more-data-button-in-a-list-of-posts-django/68785758#68785758) to see how to use ajax with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send ajax request to flask's.

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var user = $('#inputUsername').val();
        var pass = $('#inputPassword').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/signUpUser',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Flask's route

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request,json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route('/signUp')
def signUp():
    return render_template('signUp.html')

@app.route('/signUpUser', methods=['POST'])
def signUpUser():
    user =  request.form['username'];
    password = request.form['password'];
    return json.dumps({'status':'OK','user':user,'pass':password});

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

You can reference this turorial.
https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Flask/Python_Flask_with_AJAX_JQuery.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs center-block" onclick="insrow({{patient_data[0]}})">Add</button>
```

Using javascript

```
<script>
function insrow(patient_id){
    var diagname = prompt("Please enter test name", "");
    if(diagname != null){
    fetch('/adddiags/'+patient_id+'/'+ diagname).then(function(response){
            response.json().then(function(data){
                if(!("error" in data)){
            console.log(data);
            var tabbody = document.getElementById('diagtbody');
            var newrow = tabbody.insertRow(tabbody.rows.length);
            var newcell1 = newrow.insertCell(0);
            var newcell2 = newrow.insertCell(1);
            var newtext1 = document.createTextNode(data.testname);
            var newtext2 = document.createTextNode(data.price);
            newcell1.appendChild(newtext1);
            newcell2.appendChild(newtext2);
        }else{
                alert(data.error);
                }
           })
       })
   }
}
</script>
```

This goes as script inside your html

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/adddiags/<int:patient_id>/<diag_name>')
def adddiags(patient_id=0, diag_name=''):
    if patient_id:
        # fetching some information from db
        sql = text("select diagnostics_id, test_name, charge from diagnostics where test_name = :x")
        rslt = db.engine.execute(sql, x=diag_name)
        diag_data = list(rslt)
        if diag_data:
            diagnostics_id = diag_data[0][0]
            testname = diag_data[0][1]
            charge = diag_data[0][2]
            data = {"testname": testname, "price": charge}
            return jsonify(data)
        else:
            return jsonify({"error": "diagnostic test doesnt exist"})
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('diagnostics'))
```

Here in your flask app you have to write the path and db related logic. Once you receive data from db convert to json so that javascript will be able to handle it, here i am updating the same data from the api to html table. Hope this example gives a clear info.